How to add tools in navigation bar of slack using slack python sdk?
I am using Python SDK for slack. I would like to know how can I add a tool in slack navigation bar using the python sdk. Please see the image below for reference

I am using the latest slack bolt sdk. And I am kind of new to slack. So chances are I might be using wrong term for the navigation bar tool. So I am using the image for reference. Thanks for your help
